# Why dosen't my Toast Show up?

Tags: android, android-toast

I realized while writing code. toast code does not work. I copied all my code at word . I just left the toast code but still does not work.
Please help what is the problem

> package chekuptel.spmax.com.chekuptel;
>
> ```
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>
>
>
>         Toast.makeText(this,"Başlangıç",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// dont work
>
>         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Başlangıç",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //dont work
> }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: I can confirm that this exact code works for me. Can you please post your manifest?

Comment: maybe your are trying to run this code not from the main thread? i also can confirm that this code is working

Answer (score 0):

I chose my application from the applications section of the phone settings. I have solved the problem of active application notifications